# Variables in WebStorm in project with enabled only NodeJS library

Tags: autocomplete, webstorm

In WebStorm in project with enabled only NodeJS library I can see variables from other JS files when typing some variable name. Can I disable that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No. WebStorm indexes all javascript files in your project and uses this index for completion.
See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/ for some hints